# Converting Array of Int to Enum in TypeScript / Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, enums, type-conversion

In the application being built, we have an Enum created called **UserRolesEnum** like so

```
public enum UserRoleEnum {
    Aministration = 1,
    Manager = 2,
    Employee = 3
}
```

When this information is sent to the database, the **int** is stored.

On a page for displaying the users in the system, the returned in TypeScript in a component is an array an **int** array (such as [1, 2, 3]).

Using the combination of TypeScript and Angular2, the following is used to display the roles for a user:

```
<div class="role" *ngFor="let role of userRoles">
    <span>{{role}}</span>
</div>
```

What I want to show is the array as [Administration, Manager, Employee].

I've tried several different methods, but none of them have worked thus far. Is there an easy conversion that I can continue to use the array functionality?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us what you tried using a [mcve]? It might be close enough to work with a small modification.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot much, as it is part of a much larger project and it is tied to a great deal many things. These are the pieces I know that I can show for sure.

Comment: How about using a lookup table in the ngFor iteration ? So instead of `<span>{{role}}</span>`, use `<span>{{yourLookupTable[role]}}</span>` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to pass that number into the enum as an index.
Can you try this.

```
<span>{{UserRoleEnum[role]}}</span>
```

You may also need to add the enum in the component code.

```
public UserRoleEnum = UserRoleEnum;
```

or;

```
UserRoleEnum : typeof UserRoleEnum = UserRoleEnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the index of the for loop

```
<div class="role" *ngFor="let role of userRoles; let i = index">
    <span>{{i}}</span>
</div>
```